# Can the same player bid for Relics twice?

Tags: hand-of-fate-ordeals

At the end of a round when a Royalty has been eliminated, players can trade shards for a Relic Item.

If players have enough shards, can they buy into the Relic draw more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does not appear so.**

The Acquire Relic rule (Looting Royalty pg 17, base rules), specifically say that players who chooses the Acquire action must spend 5 shards (-1 per previous other acquiring player). With no leeway on additional spending, this is a set amount.

You also can not "bid" a second time after everyone else has bid, as it stats 
"Once all players have made a choice (Acquire, Exchange, Pass) ..."... move into the drawing portion of Acquiring.

> The first player then looks at the cards drawn, chooses a **single** relic to keep, and passes the remaining cards to the next player who spent Token Shards...

I agree that this is not as clear as it could be, and sometimes your relic choices just aren't worth losing that many shards. But the rules as written do say the that you many only spend an exact number of shards, and only acquire a single relic.

I am uncertain if any of the expansions change this rule, but I will update this answer if I find out.

Edit: The updated 2019 base rules on this are unchanged from the original.

Edit2: Just follow up, none of the expansions adjust this for the base game.